# Unable to prevent angular app from caching

Tags: angular, nginx, caching, service-worker, browser-cache

I am facing a cache issue in my angular app production build, I have tried building with

```
ng build --prod --outputHashing=all
```

That didn't work and I have added

```
 location / {
    root /distlocation;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate';
}
```

on nginx.

Even in index.html I have added

```html
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0, must-revalidate" />
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
   </head>
```

Even after doing all this application is not fetching latest files. Files are loaded from service-worker. If I do **force reload** latest changes are reflecting.